# Is there an irb return history?

Tags: ruby, irb

I know that it's possible to access the last return with an underscore as in:

```
irb(main):024:0> 5
=> 5
irb(main):025:0> a=_
=> 5
```

Is it possible to access the nth previous return, not command history, in any way?  Are there any gems for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `conf.eval_history`. "[irb idea: return value history](http://computer-programming-forum.com/39-ruby/a3ad68c308e06ce0.htm)" is an example of its use and is probably the closest thing I am aware of off the shelf.